# Correct terminology for 'clock' that doesn't oscillate?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, clock-speed, clock-gating

What would be the correct term for a clock input that isn't made to oscillate per se?

In an attempt to only allow input **A** to have any effect on a circuit at a chosen time, one could AND it with another input **B**.

Would input **B** still be referred to as a clock if it were to only be switched on and off manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The input B could be called "gate". Or "strobe", if the action happens on one of its edges.

It could be called "enable" or "chip select" if during it's on state it activates input A.

Answer (score 1):

Gated clocks are very common. If you're driving another chip with a SPI bus, it reduces EMC if you're not running that clock all the time. Also some SPI devices lack an enable input, so a gated clock is the only way to control transfers.

This would still be referred to as a "clock" for that SPI bus though.